# Refresh page after writting PDF to response output stream

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form on my page, when i click the submit button it sends the info to the server and the server sends back a PDF through `Context.Response.OutputStream.Write`.

What I want is for the page to reload after the PDF is saved.

What i use is these lines of codes

```
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Resources.Resources.pdfFileName)
Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
```

And i tried to add this line after those

```
Response.redirect("default.aspx")
```

But it doesn't work. It redirects before the page before the save dialog show up.

I tried to add and event to my stream, but that doesn't seem to exist.

Is there a way to wait for the outputstream to be finished until doing something else, or to have an event linked to the save dialog?

Comment: I had this same issue, and was not able to find a way to have it automatically refresh.  Thwe problem is that you have highjacked that stream that would have been used to do the refresh to make your PDF.  Closest I was able to get this to work was to add a refresh button which the user could click.  This new event kickoff could then run everthing normally

Comment: @Limey Well, this was already my backep solution if I can't get it to work the way I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. You can't redirect a request once you've written data into the response. The redirect would be done by an http header but this has to be sent to the client before any content is sent.